# I stored data in session using jsp. How can I retrieve the data using jquery?

Tags: jquery, jsp, session, get

Someone help me please.
In a jsp file, I stored a value in session as follows:
    session.setAttribute("myalias", sfl);

I would like retrieve the data in jquery (eg myjquery.js).  How can I do this please?

I have tried different plugins and examples I got on google but it is returning either null or NaN. Help please.

Comment: I gave one example below please try that it should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. The session is kept in memory (or on disk) at server-side. jQuery runs in the browser, at client side.

If you want to have data available at client-side, you need to send it to the browser.

Comment: How can I make the data available to the client? Sorry if the question sound stupid... just a newbie to web programming.

Comment: Send it as part of your web page. As a JavaScript variable, or in a hidden div, or whatever. It can't stay in the session on the server if you want it to be available in client-side JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can get the value from the session and write to the client

write the below code as inline in your jsp file , so that you will have value in the javascript and use it with jquery

```
<script>

    var testvalue= "<%=yourjspcodetogetfromsession%>"

</script>
```

Comment: How come , it should work , we do lot of stuff like this did you put this code as inline?